# Call method in Form 1 to set text from user control

Tags: c#, winforms

I found similar questions to this, but none of the answers solved my question - or perhaps I didn't understand the answers given to implement directly to my scenario.

I have started to learn Windows Forms and my question seems pretty basic.

I have a text box `myTextBox` in `Form1` and created a method in Form1.cs to set the text.

```
public void SetText(string text)
{
   myTextBox.Text = text;
}
```

I can call this from within Form1.cs and that works fine.

However I have created a user control and within that control I have a button and when I click the button I want to be able to call that `SetText` method, so I did `Form1.SetText("example")` but this gave an error for which adding 'static' to the `SetText` method resolved.

However, when I add static to `SetText` I can then no longer set the text within that method. I get the same error I had before adding static, only this time for the text box itself:
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.myTextBox'

Comment: `Text` is an instance property of the class `Form1`. `SetText` is an instance method of the class `Form1`. You cannot use instance members of a class without an instance. Both your approaches fail because `Text` need an instance. The correct way to achieve your task is to make the inner user control raise an event when the button is clicked and make the form handle that event: the event handler will then set the text either by setting the property or invoking the method.

Comment: The point of UserControls is that you can use them again in other situations.  What if you then place your UserControl in Form2?  Your code will be broken because it is trying to directly change Form1 still.  The answer is to make your UserControl raise an EVENT that passes out the string to set.  Then Form1 can subscribe to the event and set its own TextBox when the event is received.  If you then use the same UserControl in Form2, it also can subscribe to the event and set its own TextBox.  Under that setup, the UserControl would not have to be changed at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't suggest using `SetText` because it will be not compitable with other programs else.

## Suggested Solutions:

- #### `TextBox` Property:

Add in your user control `TextBox` Property and then use it.

**Code sample:**
In UserControl.cs

```cs
public TextBox TargetTextBox { get; set; }

public void SetText(string text)
{
    TargetTextBox.Text = text;
}
```

And use new method that are avaliable in UserControl

- #### Event:

Add event in the user control, and if this event fired in `Form1`, use `SetText` in code there.

**Sample Code:**
Create file called `TextEventArgs` and put this code:

```
public class TextEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public TextEventArgs(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Use this code in user control

```
public delegate void ShowTextEventHandler(object sender, TextEventArgs e);
public event ShowTextEventHandler ShowText;

// Use this method, and this method will fire 'ShowText' event
protected override OnShowText(TextEventArgs args)
{
    TextEventHandler handler = ShowText;
    handler?.Invoke(this, args);
}
```

- #### Variable (Not suggested):

Go in `Program.cs` file and put replace it with this code:

```cs
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Program
{
    internal static readonly MainForm;

    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompitableTextRenderer(false);
        MainForm = new Form1();
        Application.Run(MainForm);
    }
}
```

And then you can use `Program.MainForm.SetText("example")`.